# How to use multi-byte union between bitfields and byte arrays in C

Tags: c, struct, typedef, unions, bit-fields

I am trying to use a union between bitfields and a byte array to simplify retrieval of bytes from the bitfields.  I need to do this for transmission of packed data.  I have discovered some odd behavior with this and need help understanding what is going on.

Initially I try a union between bitfields and byte array, and this doesn't work I think because it is actually a union between bitfields and pointer to array.  Fair enough.
Instead I union to a uint16_t datatype.  This works if all my bitfields are of the same uint16_t type, but if they are uint8_t it doesn't work, by which I mean the behavior is unexpected.

Here is the struct with uint8_t bitfields:

```
typedef struct 
{
union
{
    struct
    {
        uint8_t a : 5;
        uint8_t b : 5;
        uint8_t c : 6;
    } bitfields;
    uint16_t bytes;
}onion;
} onion_struct_t;
```

I test with this code:

```
void main()
    {
        onion_struct_t x;
        x.onion.bitfields.a = 5;
        x.onion.bitfields.b = 31;
        x.onion.bitfields.c = 0;

        printf("bytes = %u\n", x.onion.bytes);
        printf("a = %u\n",  x.onion.bitfields.a);
        printf("b = %u\n", x.onion.bitfields.b);
        printf("c = %u\n",  x.onion.bitfields.c);
        getch();
    }
```

for the first line of the output, I expect "bytes" to be 997 (5 = 31 * 2^5).  However what I get is this:

```
bytes = 57285
a = 5
b = 31
c = 0
```

If I change struct to this, then it works.

```
typedef struct 
{
    union
    {
        struct
        {
            uint16_t a : 5;
            uint16_t b : 5;
            uint16_t c : 6;
        } bitfields;
        uint16_t bytes;
    }onion;
} onion_struct_t;
```

Output is as expected:

```
bytes = 997
a = 5
b = 31
c = 0
```

Question is, why do the bitfields need to be same datatype?

Update: If none of my uint8_t bitfields cross the 8 bit boundary, then it works out fine, i.e. this works as expected:

```
typedef struct 
{
    union
    {
        struct
        {
            uint8_t a : 5;
            uint8_t b : 3;
            uint8_t c : 4;
            uint8_t d : 4;
        } bitfields;
        uint16_t bytes;
    }onion;
} onion_struct_t;
```

Comment: [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) issues? Sign-extension of `bytes` when passed to `printf`? Padding of the bitfield structure? Try printing the hexadecimal representation of `bytes` to better see the bits. Also try printing `sizeof x.onion.bitfields`. And try using `"%hu"` to print `bytes`.

Comment: And better than even `"%hu"` would be `"%" PRIu16`. (See [this fixed-width and related macros reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer).)

Comment: Thank you.  i am using C, not C++, so "%hu" and "%" PRIu16 don't work.  However uysing "%x" I get "dfc5" for bytes with the uint8_t bitfields.  For uint16_t bitfields I get "03e5" which is what I expected.  sizeof(x.onion.bitfields) is "2".

Comment: The C [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) function have supported `"%hu"` since before the C99 standard. The `<stdint.h>` header (with the `uint16_t` type) and `<inttypes.h>` header (for the `PRIu16` macro) are from the C99 standard. And the size of `bitfields` is the same for *both* versions?

Comment: [You shouldn't use bit-fields for anything where size or position is important.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55823879/694733)

Comment: Thank you user694733.  Sadly bitfields are not as useful as I had hoped!  i will go the manual route.

Comment: C specifies  "A bit-field of type `_Bool`, `int`, `signed int`, or `unsigned int`". Anything else relies on a compiler extension of the language.