# How to get 63bits out of 64

Tags: c, struct, union

I have some 32bits memory area filled from hardware with this type of data :

```
reg1 :    63  |  62  |  ... | 32     |  reg0 :   31| ... | 0
        --------------------------   |          ----------------
         val  | time value upper     |          time value lower
```

I'm trying to get the time value and the 'val' at once with **struct** and **union**.

I first tried :

```
typedef struct
{
    uint64_t time   : 63;
    uint64_t value  :  1;
} myStruct;
```

but this is not working, `myStruct.time` cannot be bigger than 32bits.

I tried several things, event somethign like this :

```
typedef union
{
    union{
        struct{
            uint32_t lower : 32;
            uint32_t upper : 31;
        } spare;
        uint64_t value;
    } time;
    struct{
        uint32_t spare_low : 32;
        uint32_t spare_upp : 31;
        uint32_t value : 1;
    } pin;
} myStruct;
```

But in this case, `myStruct.time.value` get obviously the bit 63. I get some values like 0x8000_0415_4142_3015 instead of 0x0000_0415_4142_3015.

How can I retrieve the 63 bits time value and the 1 bit pin value easily ?

PS : I know that I can make a macro of something like that, I'm looking for a direct method.

Comment: If your system does not support larger than 32 bit bitfields, you cannot do what you want, and you'd have to read the whole 64 bit value and mask out the top(MSB) bit yourself. (Which is what the compiler probably would do anyway using a struct with bitfields)

Comment: Edit the question to supply further information: Does your C implementation support `uint64_t` (as a plain type; the question indicates it does not work as a bit-field type, but does it exist at all in your C implementation?)? How do you have or receive the contents of `reg1` and `reg0`? Do you have them in an array of two `uint32_t`? If so, is `reg0` in the element with index 0 or index 1? Do you have them in one `uint64_t`? If so, is `reg0` in bits 31-0 (the low bits) or bits 63-32 (the high bits)? Or something else?

Answer (score 2):

[Bitfields should never be used when bit placement is important.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55825057/694733)

Use bit masking instead:

```
uint64_t someValue = ...
uint64_t time = someValue & 0x7fffffffffffffff;
bool pin = someValue >> 63 & 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Bit-fields only gives head ache and non-portable code. Always avoid them.

Assuming that 64 bit access is feasible for your specific system and "reg1" and "reg0" aren't actual variables but something placed in memory by hardware, then:

```
#define reg1 (*(volatile uint32_t*)0x1000) // address of reg1
#define reg0 (*(volatile uint32_t*)0x1004) // address of reg0

const uint32_t VAL_MASK = 1ul << 31;
...
uint64_t time_;
time_  = (uint64_t)(reg1 & (VAL_MASK - 1)) << 32;
time_ |= reg0;

bool val = reg1 & VAL_MASK; 
// or alternatively:
uint64_t val = reg1 >> 31;
```

(Please don't name your variable `time` since that collides with the standard lib.)

If you don't have 64 bit types or in case they are simply too slow to use, then you have to access each 32 bits individually, just don't OR them together as done above.

Answer (score 0):

```
int getval(uint64_t reg)
{
    return !!(reg & ((uint64_t)1 << 63));
}

uint64_t gettime(uint64_t reg)
{
   return reg & (~((uint64_t)1 << 63));
}
```