# struct bit field in C

Tags: c, struct

I am having this structure

```
 typedef struct {

  uint8_t sw_reset                 : 1;
  uint8_t ble                      : 1;
  uint8_t if_inc                   : 1;
  uint8_t sim                      : 1;
  uint8_t pp_od                    : 1;
  uint8_t h_lactive                : 1;
  uint8_t bdu                      : 1;
  uint8_t boot                     : 1;

} lsm6dsl_ctrl3_c_t;
```

This the main

```
    int main()
{
    lsm6dsl_ctrl3_c_t   ctrl3_c;

    ctrl3_c.sw_reset   = 0;
    ctrl3_c.ble        = 1;
    ctrl3_c.if_inc     = 1;
    ctrl3_c.sim        = 1;
    ctrl3_c.pp_od      = 1;
    ctrl3_c.h_lactive  = 1;
    ctrl3_c.bdu        = 1;
    ctrl3_c.boot       = 1;

    printf("ctrl3_c 0x%x\n", ctrl3_c);

    return 0;
}
```

when i compile, i have this warning

```
warning: format '%x' expects argument of type 'unsigned int', but argument 2 has type 'lsm6dsl_ctrl3_c_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' [-Wformat=]
```

output is

```
ctrl3_c 0x4019fe
```

How can i fix the warning?  I was expecting 0xfe output but got 0x4019fe.  And, how can I assign the 0xfe to an uint8_t variable?

Comment: It seems what you want is a *union* containing the bit-field and an `uint8_t` member.

Comment: Sidenote: It seems like you are using bitfield to do some kind of mapping, and if that is the case, you are relying on compiler to play nice. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55823879/694733) on why using bitfields is troublesome when exact placement of bits is important.

Comment: @Some programmer dude  yes, you are right.   i am trying to understand a sample code by separating the parts but it is complicated for me.  Can you help me by providing an example?

Comment: @user694733 thanks. I'll check the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning explains the real issue. Passing the wrong type for a format specifier is undefined behavior, which is the reason for your odd result.

Using a `union` with an anonymous `struct` and an extra `uint8_t` member to access the whole thing as a byte should do the trick:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef union {
  struct
  {
    uint8_t sw_reset                 : 1;
    uint8_t ble                      : 1;
    uint8_t if_inc                   : 1;
    uint8_t sim                      : 1;
    uint8_t pp_od                    : 1;
    uint8_t h_lactive                : 1;
    uint8_t bdu                      : 1;
    uint8_t boot                     : 1;
  };
  uint8_t byte;
} lsm6dsl_ctrl3_c_t;

int main()
{
    lsm6dsl_ctrl3_c_t   ctrl3_c;

    ctrl3_c.sw_reset   = 0;
    ctrl3_c.ble        = 1;
    ctrl3_c.if_inc     = 1;
    ctrl3_c.sim        = 1;
    ctrl3_c.pp_od      = 1;
    ctrl3_c.h_lactive  = 1;
    ctrl3_c.bdu        = 1;
    ctrl3_c.boot       = 1;

    printf("ctrl3_c %#x\n", ctrl3_c.byte);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
ctrl3_c 0xfe
```

Comment: Thank you for the simple explanation and solution.

Comment: @iAM3 if my answer helped solve your issue/works for you, you can [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking the checkmark under the votes :)